# Would a beam of light moving through a vacuum be considered an example of perpetual motion?

Tags: speed-of-light, vacuum, perpetual-motion

I have a very limited understanding of Physics but if the beam of light was moving through a vacuum like space and had saw no obstuctions during its path, would that be perpetual motion in action?

Comment: Any questions that requires "be considered" is automatically suspect of being about opinion. Who do you propose is doing the considering? In an infinite, empty universe you could consider that way if you wanted to, but it would not be an interesting thing to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The speed of any object is constant if there are no forces acting on the object.  This applies to light and all other matter.  Without forces (e.g. friction), an object that is moving will never stop moving.

By "perpetual motion" people usually mean a machine that can produce more work than the work required to run it.  It's hard to think of an everyday example of this because there isn't one.  But, you could imagine a bicycle that uses its own wheel rotation to increase its speed.

Answer (score 0):

Any phenomenon in the universe follows the principle of conservation of energy. Perpetual motion is possible when no external force acts on an object and the object is moving with constant velocity. The answer to your question is "yes". This is the reason why we can observe stars that are millions of light years away from us. In our universe this motion is near perpetual. Because space between two astronomical object is not completely vacuum. There are traces of elements but very less per cubic meter. If the question is "Is propagation of light in our universe perpetual?". Answer is "no". It is near perpetual.